# How to get rack id or consumer information from a custom PartitionAssignor implementation

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to implement a custom Kafka PartitionAssignor based on rack-awareness. My custom assignor will override the subscription method to be able to read consumer's instance information:

```java
    /**
     * Return a serializable object representing the local member's subscription. This can include
     * additional information as well (e.g. local host/rack information) which can be leveraged in
     * {@link #assign(Cluster, Map)}.
     * @param topics Topics subscribed to through {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer#subscribe(java.util.Collection)}
     *               and variants
     * @return Non-null subscription with optional user data
     */
    Subscription subscription(Set<String> topics);
```

The idea in this method is to read the current consumer's instance information like rack.id to be published to ConsumerCoordinator that will forward them to assign() method.  Unfortunately, I have not found a mechanism to get consumer's information because at runtime there is no reference to it. The question is: How can I get consumer's instance information from my custom Kafka PartitionAssignor implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

class Subscription has a byte buffer for you to put arbitrary data into:

```
class Subscription {
    private final List<String> topics;
    private final ByteBuffer userData; <---- HERE
}
```

you set this data in the `PartitionAssignor` that every consumer must run.
then this Subscription (data included) is handed to the `PartitionAssignor` on some chosen consumer to compute the new assignment:

```
Map<String, Assignment> assign(Cluster metadata, Map<String, Subscription> subscriptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!. Now I want to create a userData by using a consumer's instance information. For example. the user Data should be created with consumer client.id, rack.id etc... How can reach the consumer instance from subscription method.

Comment: you cant from within the method (is doesnt give you those arguments) but you can save anything you need when you create the consumer itself (when you build the properties object) for use at this stage

Comment: Great! Thanks again!